fullscreenCover inside NavigationStack is redrawn when Apples subscription controller is presented
I have a NavigationStack, inside which there is a button. Tapping on the button presents Apple's SubscriptionStoreView inside fullScreenCover . I was surprised that when I tap on "Subscribe" inside the view, and Apple's controller for completing the purchase is presented/dismissed, it cause the fullScreenCover  to be redrawn causing a flicker and to reset the state of the store view.
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSubscriptionScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Label("Subscribe", systemImage:"crown.fill")
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingSubscriptionScreen) {
                                SubscriptionStoreView(groupID: "4CD3E8A1")
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                isShowingSubscriptionScreen = true
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


Further I was surprised that removing the HStack section solved the issue.
I can solve this easily by attaching the fullScreenCover to a different view outside of the navigation stack, however I would like to know the explanation of why it is happening. How does Apple's controller can affect the state and cause a redrawing of my views even if there is no state.

StateObject isn’t for singletons

@malhal Thanks, I will look into it separately. I updated the code without it and still have the issue. I will update the code in the question.

The state problem is because you haven't called the isShowingSubscriptionScreen getter anywhere. This is because your source of truth is wrong, it shouldnt be a boolean but be the groupID you want to show, e.g. something like this:
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var showGroupID: Group.ID? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Label("Subscribe", systemImage:"crown.fill")
                            .fullScreenCover(item: $showGroupID) { groupID in
                                SubscriptionStoreView(groupID: groupID)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showGroupID = "4CD3E8A1"
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}


I implemented this change and it did not make a difference. Can you explain why isShowingSubscriptionScreen getter should be called and why groupID should be the source of truth? groupID is just a constant literal, what relation does it have to state?
